# How to run NSTask with multiple commands

Tags: objective-c, nstask

I'm trying to make a NSTask running a command like this:

> ps -clx | grep 'Finder' | awk '{print $2}'

Here is my method

```
- (void) processByName:(NSString*)name {
    NSTask *task1 = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    NSPipe *pipe1 = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task1 waitUntilExit];
    [task1 setLaunchPath: @"/bin/ps"];
    [task1 setArguments: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-clx", nil]];
    [task1 setStandardOutput: pipe1];

    NSTask *task2 = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    NSPipe *pipe2 = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task2 setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/grep"];
    [task2 setArguments: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"'Finder'", nil]];
    [task2 setStandardInput:pipe1];
    [task2 setStandardOutput: pipe2];

    NSTask *task3 = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    NSPipe *pipe3 = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task3 setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/grep"];
    [task3 setArguments: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"'{print $2}'", nil]];
    [task3 setStandardInput:pipe2];
    [task3 setStandardOutput: pipe3];

    NSFileHandle *file = [pipe3 fileHandleForReading];

    [task1 launch];
    [task2 launch];
    [task3 launch];

    NSData *data;
    data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

    NSString *string;
    string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Result: %@", string);
}
```

But the result is just

> Result:

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

```
- (void) processByName:(NSString*)name {
    NSTask *task1 = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    NSPipe *pipe1 = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task1 waitUntilExit];
    [task1 setLaunchPath: @"/bin/ps"];
    [task1 setArguments: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-clx", nil]];
    [task1 setStandardOutput: pipe1];

    NSTask *task2 = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    NSPipe *pipe2 = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task2 setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/grep"];
    [task2 setArguments: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"'Finder'", nil]];
    [task2 setStandardInput:pipe1];
    [task2 setStandardOutput: pipe2];

    NSTask *task3 = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    NSPipe *pipe3 = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task3 setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/grep"];
    [task3 setArguments: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"'{print $2}'", nil]];
    [task3 setStandardInput:pipe2];
    [task3 setStandardOutput: pipe3];

    NSFileHandle *file = [pipe3 fileHandleForReading];

    [task1 launch];
    [task2 launch];
    [task3 launch];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSTaskDidTerminateNotification
                                                      object:task3
                                                       queue:nil
                                                  usingBlock:^(NSNotification* notification){

                                                      NSData * data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

                                                      NSString * string;
                                                      string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                      NSLog(@"Result: %@", string);
                                                  }];
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to launch the tasks after you have attached the observer? What if a task completes before the observer is attached?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tasks run in a separate process from your code, i.e., asychronously. They probably haven't finished (they may not have even launched!) by the time you get to the `readDataToEndOfFile` two lines later.

If you're already on a background thread here, you can poll their status: `while( ![task isRunning]){`, or if you're on the main thread, I'd suggest using GCD to put this onto a queue and doing the polling there.

Actually, better than that would be to use notifications:

```
[task3 launch];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSTaskDidTerminateNotification
                                                  object:task3
                                                   queue:nil
                                              usingBlock:^{

    NSData * data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

    NSString * string;
    string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Result: %@", string);
}];
```

See [TN2050: Observing Process Lifetime Without Polling](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2050/_index.html). Each `NSTask` will send `NSTaskDidTerminateNotification` when it terminates (you should, ideally, check its return code rather than assuming it ran successfully). You can create a block to be run when `task3` sends that notification.

Comment: Could you please provide me with a small example showing how I can do this using GCD?

Comment: You know, I just thought of a better way to do this. Please see my edit.

Comment: Please see my edit. I've added the code, but I still returns an empty string.

Comment: Have you verified that the command string you're running does what you expect if you just enter it to the CL? I see two things that look funny: you're not using the argument to the method, and you're running `grep '{print $2}'` as the third task -- did you mean `awk`?

Comment: I cannot get the right result from the code "Edit" part

Answer (score 2):

The following code works for me.

```
NSTask *task1 = [[NSTask alloc] init];
NSPipe *pipe1 = [NSPipe pipe];
[task1 waitUntilExit];
[task1 setLaunchPath: @"/bin/sh"];
[task1 setArguments: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-c",@"ps -A |grep -m1 Finder | awk '{print $1}'", nil]];
[task1 setStandardOutput: pipe1];
[task1 launch];

NSFileHandle *file = [pipe1 fileHandleForReading];
NSData * data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

NSString * string;
string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Result: %@", string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost 8 years later, I think grep binary is'nt in /usr/bin, for me it's in /bin. Also, for your awk command, you set the launch path to grep.