# Get terminal output after a command swift

Tags: swift, terminal, console-output

I run some commands in terminal with this code:

```
system("the command here")
```

And after I want to know what is the result of running this command, e.g. if I run

```
system("git status")
```

I want to read the actual information about changes in my repo. Is there any way to do that in swift?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xcode 6 swift system() command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399301/xcode-6-swift-system-command).

Comment: @MartinR, there's no information about the way to run multiple commands at once or run commands in one session

Comment: To execute a command and capture its output, you have to use NSTask. For multiple commands, create and execute multiple NSTasks.

Comment: you could always use `popen` if you’re really enthusiastic about using C functions :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`NSTask` is class to run another program as a subprocess. You can 
capture the program's output, error output, exit status and much more.

Expanding on my answer to [xcode 6 swift system() command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399301/xcode-6-swift-system-command),
here is a simple utility function to run a command synchronously,
and return the output, error output and exit code (now updated for Swift 2):

```
func runCommand(cmd : String, args : String...) -> (output: [String], error: [String], exitCode: Int32) {

    var output : [String] = []
    var error : [String] = []

    let task = NSTask()
    task.launchPath = cmd
    task.arguments = args

    let outpipe = NSPipe()
    task.standardOutput = outpipe
    let errpipe = NSPipe()
    task.standardError = errpipe

    task.launch()

    let outdata = outpipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    if var string = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer(outdata.bytes)) {
        string = string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())
        output = string.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
    }

    let errdata = errpipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    if var string = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer(errdata.bytes)) {
        string = string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())
        error = string.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
    }

    task.waitUntilExit()
    let status = task.terminationStatus

    return (output, error, status)
}
```

Sample usage:

```
let (output, error, status) = runCommand("/usr/bin/git", args: "status")
print("program exited with status \(status)")
if output.count > 0 {
    print("program output:")
    print(output)
}
if error.count > 0 {
    print("error output:")
    print(error)
}
```

Or, if you are only interested in the output, but not in 
the error messages or exit code:

```
let output = runCommand("/usr/bin/git", args: "status").output
```

Output and error output are returned as an array of strings, one
string for each line.

The first argument to `runCommand()` must be the full path to an
executable, such as `"/usr/bin/git"`. You can start the program using a shell (which is what `system()` also does):

```
let (output, error, status) = runCommand("/bin/sh", args: "-c", "git status")
```

The advantage is that the "git" executable is automatically found
via the default search path. The disadvantage is that you have to
quote/escape arguments correctly if they contain spaces or other
characters which have a special meaning in the shell.

---

Update for **Swift 3:**

```
func runCommand(cmd : String, args : String...) -> (output: [String], error: [String], exitCode: Int32) {

    var output : [String] = []
    var error : [String] = []

    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = cmd
    task.arguments = args

    let outpipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = outpipe
    let errpipe = Pipe()
    task.standardError = errpipe

    task.launch()

    let outdata = outpipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    if var string = String(data: outdata, encoding: .utf8) {
        string = string.trimmingCharacters(in: .newlines)
        output = string.components(separatedBy: "\n")
    }

    let errdata = errpipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    if var string = String(data: errdata, encoding: .utf8) {
        string = string.trimmingCharacters(in: .newlines)
        error = string.components(separatedBy: "\n")
    }

    task.waitUntilExit()
    let status = task.terminationStatus

    return (output, error, status)
}
```

Comment: I still can't run multiple programs in one session. For example, if the output for `status` doesn't contain words "nothing" and "clear" (some changes were made) I need to run `git add .` and then `git commit` and `git push origin master`

Comment: @NikitinRoman: What do you mean with "one session"? Can't you run `runCommand("/usr/bin/git", "status")` first and then `runCommand("/usr/bin/git", "add", ".")` and finally `runCommand("/usr/bin/git", "push", "origin", "master")` ?

Comment: I firstly I need to run `cd Project` and after it one by one all this commands, without changing directory

Comment: @NikitinRoman: Now I see what you mean. NSTask has a currentDirectoryPath property, that can be set to the directory where the command should be executed. I'll update the code ...

Comment: @NikitinRoman: You are welcome! – Note that "cd" is *shell built-in*. If you type "cd project" in the shell, no external command is executed, the shell just remembers the new working directory and uses it as current working directory for the next commands.

Comment: Something strange started to happen.. every time I run the program, it shows signal SIGABRT on line `task.launch()` and shows this error:  `2015-04-09 18:36:50.224 Commit changes[34595:9180071] An uncaught exception was raised
2015-04-09 18:36:50.224 Commit changes[34595:9180071] launch path not accessible`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74873/discussion-between-martin-r-and-nikitin-roman).

Comment: Updated for Swift 2:  let (output, error, status) = runCommand("/usr/bin/git", args: "status")
        print("program exited with status \(status)")
        if output.count > 0 {
            print("program output:")
            print(output)
        }
        if error.count > 0 {
            print("error output:")
            print(error)
        }

Comment: Can anyone update the UnsafePointer usage to Swift 3?

Comment: @Narwhal: I did not have the time to update it before now.

Comment: @Michal: Thanks for suggesting an improvement. The above Swift 3 does still work with Swift 5 (I just tested it). You are welcome to post your suggested code as an answer.

Comment: If I want to get the asni code through NSTask, can you tell me how to do it? I want to render the colors myself.@MartinR

Answer (score 3):

`system` spawns a new process so you can’t capture its ouput.  The equivalent that gives you a way to do this would be `popen`, which you could use like this:

```
import Darwin

let fp = popen("ping -c 4 localhost", "r")
var buf = Array<CChar>(count: 128, repeatedValue: 0)

while fgets(&buf, CInt(buf.count), fp) != nil,
      let str = String.fromCString(buf) {
    print(str)
}

fclose(fp)
```

However, don’t do it this way.  Use `NSTask` as [Martin describes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399301/xcode-6-swift-system-command).

edit: based on your request to run multiple commands in parallel, here is some probably-unwise code:

```
import Darwin

let commands = [
    "tail /etc/hosts",
    "ping -c 2 localhost",
]

let fps = commands.map { popen($0, "r") }

var buf = Array<CChar>(count: 128, repeatedValue: 0)

let results: [String] = fps.map { fp  in
    var result = ""
    while fgets(&buf, CInt(buf.count), fp) != nil,
          let str = String.fromCString(buf) {
        result += str
    }
    return result
}

fps.map { fclose($0) }

println("\n\n----\n\n".join(map(zip(commands,results)) { "\($0):\n\($1)" }))
```

(seriously, use `NSTask`)

Comment: The second argument to `fgets()` should be the actual buffer size :) – One reason that I avoid `popen()` if possible is that you have to quote/escape the arguments correctly if they contain spaces or any special she'll characters, that can get ugly.

Comment: D’oh!  You’re right of course, I mostly post this because I’m amazed the C interop is so smooth.

Comment: is there any way to run multiple commands one by one and get output for each of them?

Comment: @Nikitin Roman: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400287/how-to-run-nstask-with-multiple-commands    An alternative is to call .sh file that has your multiple commands.

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cents for swift 5.x , macOS with call back, invoked when done.

```
final func doTaskFor(cmd: String, arguments: [String], callback: CallBackWithStr = nil){


let task = Process()

let absolutePath = <add your specific path..> 
let fullCmd = absolutePath+cmd

#if DEBUG
// used to debug.
let debugstr :String = fullCmd + " " + arguments.oneLine()
print(debugstr)

#endif

task.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: fullCmd)
task.arguments = arguments

// Create 2 Pipes and make the task
let outPipe = Pipe()
task.standardOutput = outPipe

let errPipe = Pipe()
task.standardError = errPipe

task.terminationHandler = { (process) in
    
    print("\ndidFinish: \(!process.isRunning)")
    
    // Get the data
    let outData = outPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = String(data: outData, encoding: .utf8)
    // print(output!)
    
    // Get the error
    let errData = errPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let err = String(data: errData, encoding: .utf8)
    // print(err!)
    
    // usually output is empty if error.
    
    callback?(output ?? "")
    
}

do {
    try task.run()
} catch {
    let msg = " \(error)"
    Log(msg: msg, safe: true)
    print(msg)
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

Tu run your commands and get its outputs you can use next simple extention of `Process` class:

```swift
extension String : LocalizedError {
    public var errorDescription: String? { self }
}

extension Process {
    
    func run(_ executableURL: URL, arguments: [String]? = nil) throws -> String {
        self.executableURL = executableURL
        self.arguments = arguments
        
        let pipe = Pipe()
        standardOutput = pipe
        standardError = pipe
        
        try run()
        waitUntilExit()
        
        guard terminationStatus == EXIT_SUCCESS else {
            let error = String(data: pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile(), encoding: .utf8)
            throw (error?.trimmingCharacters(in: .newlines) ?? "")
        }
        
        let output = String(data: pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile(), encoding: .utf8)
        return output?.trimmingCharacters(in: .newlines) ?? ""
    }
}
```

How to use:

```swift
let process = Process()

do {
    let output = try process.run(URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/zsh"), arguments: ["-c", "echo 'hello'"])
    print("Output: \(output)")
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
print("Status: \(process.terminationStatus)")
```

Outputs:

```bash
Output: hello
Status: 0
```