# How to use UnsafePointer with Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, c-strings, unsafe-pointers

I am trying to use the function made by Martin R as an answer to this question: [Get terminal output after a command swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514738/get-terminal-output-after-a-command-swift)

However, the UnsafePointer line no longer works with Swift 3 and I'm having trouble figuring it out. How would I adapt this code to Swift 3?

```
if var string = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer(outdata.bytes)) {
    string = string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())
    output = string.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
}
```

ps, You need to "Import Cocoa" if you want to trying using the function.

Comment: Thinking about the referenced code again, using `String.fromCString()` there was perhaps not the best solution. I'll update that later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 3, `readDataToEndOfFile()` returns a `Data` value, not `NSData`.
The answer to your direct question would be

```
let data: Data = ...
let string = data.withUnsafeBytes { String(cString: UnsafePointer<CChar>($0)) }
```

However, that requires a NUL-terminated sequence of bytes (so that wasn't
my smartest idea in [Get terminal output after a command swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514738/get-terminal-output-after-a-command-swift/29519615#29519615) and I'll update
that later).

Better use `String(data: encoding:)`:

```
let outdata = outpipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
if var string = String(data: outdata, encoding: .utf8) {
    string = string.trimmingCharacters(in: .newlines)
    output = string.components(separatedBy: "\n")
}
```