# Reading the MOTD msg of terminal In Mojave

Tags: terminal, operating-system, macos-mojave

I am creating an application just like terminal. For that i want to display the MOTD msg as its dispalyed in terminal on launch. How to get this msg in objective C / Swift.

Couldnt find a soultion for this in net. etc/motd file is not present in the system.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge the `motd` messages are generated by a bash script at `/etc/motd`.

So you basically need to execute the script either by `Objective-C` or `Swift` and grab the output

- [Objective C sample](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/213145/objective-c-launching-nstask-to-run-a-shell-script-and-get-output)
- [Swift sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514738/get-terminal-output-after-a-command-swift)

Comment: Unable to find this file in directory /etc/motd

Comment: @Angel I think that is the script and it is not a directory, just try to check the content.